# Insert PDF into Word document on PC without converting file format

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2016

I recently switched operating systems from a Mac to a PC. On a Mac, you can drag or insert PDFs into Word documents, and Word recognizes them as vector files. When I open those Word documents on my PC, Word still recognizes those them as vector files, which I know because I can zoom in arbitrarily without loss of resolution, and the document size is not that large. However, if I insert a new PDF into a Word document, it becomes rasterized. Is there a way to force Word to recognize PDFs as vector files on a PC? It seems like it should have the capability to do so because it isn't converting the PDFs that are already in the document.

I do have Adobe, but when I click Insert Object -> Adobe Acrobat Document, the file is getting converted. On a Mac, I think I could insert PDFs via the Insert Picture option, but that does not seem to work on PDFs on a PC.

Would like to avoid proprietary file formats because I'm creating the PDFs in R. I'm using Word 2016 and Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Windows Word add-in for that. See [PDFpasteup.com addin](https://PDFpasteup.com) for a free trial version.

The add-in imports PDF pages, or parts of pages, as EMF-formatted vector graphics so there's no rasterization. Any raster images are imported at the full, original resolution of the PDF. The add-in will let you set up Mail Merge variables to automate the process if this is a job you do regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Google Account? Use its Google Docs to open the PDF and download the PDF file as Word, you will be able to insert the PDF contents into a Word.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Office 2016 and [Microsoft 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c), Microsoft Office finally supports Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG). So you can convert your PDF to SVGs and insert them into your Office document.

You can use [`pdf2svg`](https://cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) to convert your (multi-page) PDF into (multiple) SVGs:

```
pdf2svg input.pdf output_%d.svg all
```